# Child class accessing Parent's public methods

Tags: c++, object-oriented, c++14

I have a data structure consisting of one main `Parent` container that allows direct access to the `Child` objects it contains. These `Child` objects all have their own data, but also have some shared data (in the example provided, `importantIndices`). To prevent data duplication between the thousands of `Child` objects, I've stored the shared data in the `Parent` object, and passed a pointer to the `Parent` to each child, which they can use to access the shared data.

The issues are that I feel that this breaks OOP encapsulation, and it makes it hard to test because the objects are tightly coupled. However, it also seems to be the best option - in the real scenario, there's enough shared data and enough `Child` objects that duplication is not an option. Is there a better way to implement this concept that allows for less coupling, while keeping the data available to all `Child` objects?

Unfortunately, even the names of the actual objects would be giving away proprietary information, so here I've provided a minimal working example of the problem I'm facing. Also, if this would be more appropriate at a different stackexchange site then please direct me there, but it didn't feel as much like a `stackoverflow` or `softwareengineering` question as a `codereview`.

Provided below are a `Child` class, a `Parent` class, and a basic example of their use in `main.cpp`. Note that I also have Qt and C++14 available, if those could help.

`child.h`:

```
#ifndef CHILD_H
#define CHILD_H

#include <vector>

using std::vector;

class Parent;

class Child
{
    /* This feels awkward - a circular dependency of sorts that breaks
     * encapsulation entirely.
     */
    Parent* myParent;

    /* Some arbitrary integer data. */
    vector<int> myData;

public:
    Child(Parent* parent, int totalIndices);

    void setData(int index, int data);
    int sumImportantData() const;
};

#endif // CHILD_H
```

`child.cpp`:

```
#include "child.h"
#include "parent.h"

/* Constructor. Initializes myData with size totalIndices. */
Child::Child(Parent* parent, int totalIndices) :
    myParent(parent),
    myData(totalIndices)
{}

/* Sets the data at the given index. */
void Child::setData(int index, int data)
{
    myData[index] = data;
}

/* Returns the sum of the data at the important indices. */
int Child::sumImportantData() const
{
    const vector<int> &indices = myParent->getImportantIndices();

    int sum = 0;
    for (auto iter = indices.cbegin(); iter != indices.cend(); ++iter) {
        sum += myData[*iter];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

`parent.h`:

```
#ifndef PARENT_H
#define PARENT_H

#include <vector>
#include "child.h"

using std::vector;

class Parent {
    /* Container of child objects. */
    vector<Child> childVect;

    /* Data indices that are actually important - we store data at all indices,
     * but don't use that data in most cases. We only use the data at the
     * important indices for data analysis.
     */
    const vector<int> importantIndices;

public:
    /* Constructor. Initializes numChildren children with totalIndices points
     * of data, where the important indices are in importantIndices.
     */
    Parent(int numChildren, int totalIndices,
           const vector<int> &importantIndices) :
        importantIndices(importantIndices)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < numChildren; ++index) {
            childVect.push_back(Child(this, totalIndices));
        }
    }

    /* Returns a const reference to the vector of important indices. */
    const vector<int> &getImportantIndices() const
    {
        return importantIndices;
    }

    /* Allows direct access to Child objects. */
    Child& operator[](int index)
    {
        return childVect[index];
    }

};

#endif // PARENT_H
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "parent.h"

int main()
{
    int numIndices = 7;
    Parent container = Parent(200 * 200, numIndices, std::vector<int>{2, 4, 5});

    for (int i = 0; i < numIndices; ++i) {
        container[235].setData(i, i * 100);
    }

    std::cout << container[235].sumImportantData() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why couldn't the parent object allocate some shared data container and inform each of its childrem about that container, but not about himself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that the `Child` doesn't necessarily need a reference/pointer to a concrete `Parent` - it wants to reference one of the *interfaces* that `Parent` implements.  Specifically, a `SharedChildData` interface (you can think of a better name - it's a bit difficult with borderline-offtopic placeholder code).

---

Or perhaps it makes sense to decouple child and parent by *passing* the `importantIndices` collection to the method?  Like this:

```
// in Child
int sumImportantData(const vector<int>& indices) const;
```

Then you could ask the parent to sum important data of a particular child

```
// in Parent
int getChildSum(size_t child_index) const;
// or pass an iterator etc instead of index
```

---

`Child` has no copy or assignment, and uses the parent pointer without checking - that smells like a reference would be better than a pointer.  Also, if you don't need to modify the parent from the child (and if you do, that's a danger sign for the design), then prefer a reference to `const`:

```
class Child
{
    const Parent& myParent;
    // or const SharedChildData& mySharedChildData;

    // ...
};
```

---

This method looks cumbersome:

```
int Child::sumImportantData() const
{
    const vector<int> &indices = myParent->getImportantIndices();

    int sum = 0;
    for (auto iter = indices.cbegin(); iter != indices.cend(); ++iter) {
        sum += myData[*iter];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

A range-based `for` loop would be clearer and shorter:

```
int Child::sumImportantData() const
{
    const auto& indices = myParent->getImportantIndices();

    int sum = 0;
    for (auto& i: indices) {
        sum += myData[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

You might be able to get something even clearer using `std::accumulate()`.

Comment: That works perfectly. I moved the shared data out of the `Parent` and into its own class that gets constructed by the `Parent` and passed in to the `Child` class' constructor, in which it's stored by reference. Works as intended with a relatively clean interface, and is much more easily testable/mockable. Thanks!

Comment: It's very gratifying to know that my review was helpful.  The accept vote is appreciated; the comments even more.